# Dynamic CSS styles for numbered styles

Tags: html, css

I have four animations with various delays. Specifically, I have four CSS styles, each one for each delay.

They are:

`.delay-1, .delay-2, .delay-3, .delay-4`. So the format is `.delay-[number]`. Each of which has a delay of `number*400ms`. Is it possible to have some kind of function that allows me to dynamically set the delay? So if I had .delay-6, the delay would be 6*400ms or 2400ms.

I cannot seem to find anything on Google or stackoverflow for this. Perhaps I am querying for the wrong thing/using the wrong wording.

I would prefer to do this with pure CSS if possible.

Comment: With vanilla css, no it is not possible. However, using a css preprocessor (such as SASS or LESS) you can assign dynamic values to css properties.

Comment: No...CSS can't do that. You need javascript.

Comment: Even pre-processors output CSS...so, although it would be easier and quicker to *write*, you'd still end up with the same **output CSS**.

Comment: I have an `app.scss` file -- so does this mean it is possible?

Comment: How would we know? We don't have the file...but the answer is still "no". CSS doesn't work that way.

Comment: Answer is no. But there might be a solution which you could use, by doing data-attribute on the element and then call that into the css.

Comment: Your best bet might actually be green sock's library, it's amazingly easy to use: http://greensock.com/gsap

Comment: Given that your range of possible delays should be considered `1-infinity`, might you consider directly setting each element's `animation-delay` property on its style attribute? There are plenty of legitimate reasons to avoid directly setting styles, but this is something that tends to be much cleaner through that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming that naming convention is .delay-[number] I wrote a function which calculates delay for a particular class and set css property 'animation-delay' of clicked class to calculated delay. lets say if you click on class .delay-6 the animation-delay property of that class will be set to 2400ms.

```
$('[class^="delay-"]').click(function(){
  var num = this.className.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
  var delay = num * 400+'ms';
  this.style.animationDelay = delay;
  console.log("delay for class " + this.className+ " is " + delay);
});
```

You can adjust this method according to your usecase. I don't know what should trigger the delay calculation in your case so made it on click.

Here is a jsbin so you can play with it: http://jsbin.com/jumomayapo/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please disregard the button "try it" in the jsbin, It does nothing, I just forgot to remove it.

P.S. Pure css solution doesn't seem to be possible.